# How to successfully restore a backup using pg_dump in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postrgresql. I want to create a backup of a production database and restore it in my development instance. Before I touch production, however, I want to make and restore a backup in development. I figured this would be a trivial effort, but that has not been the case.

I connected to psql using the command below.

> sudo -u postgres psql

I ran the following command to create my backup inside psql.

> \ pg_dump -U postgres -d dbname > /tmp/kp.bak

I included the "!" with the ""of the command above, but Stackoverflow is having trouble rendering that combination of characters

After that it prompted for a password. When I give it the correct password I get the following error. I reset the password for the PostgreSQL user using the ALTER PASSWORD command, so I know I have the correct password.

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgresql"

Since that doesn't work, I configured the pg_hba.conf to not require one and restarted the service. This has had no effect, as I am still prompted for a password when I try to restore. This is the first uncommented line in pg_hba.conf.

> local   all             all                                     trust

Here is the command I am using to do the restore.

> \ pg_dump -U postgresql -h localhost -f \tmp\kp.bak dbname;

I am at a loss at how to move forward with this. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it to work with the following commands

> sudo -U postgres psql

Then

> \! pg_dump -U postgres -d dbname > /tmp/dbname.bak

Doing this outside of psql did not work. I received the following error despite running with sudo.

> bash: /tmp/dbname.bak: Permission denied

Comment: Careful with this answer. Using this, I lost my dbname.bak. Running this I got access error and then the entire file was CLEAN, 0kb, like after using touch. My dump was ERASED

Answer (score 0):

Starting `psql` just to shell out to `pg_dump` doesn't make any sense.  Just do it directly:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump ....
```

But once you have moved away from "peer" as your authentication method, there is no point in using the sudo at all, so just do it even more directly:

```
pg_dump ....
```

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgresql"

I don't find it believable that you specified `-U postgres`, yet the error message says `user "postgresql"`.  Please double check your post for spelling and typing errors.

Comment: The final command in question was: ```\ pg_dump -U postgresql -h localhost -f \tmp\kp.bak dbname;``` which is where ```"postgresql"``` came from.